# Can I add fonts missing from Google Docs that are in MS Word?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, font, microsoft-word

I create my documents using Microsoft Word 2007. I then upload them to Google Docs so that they are always available for me to edit/rework.

In Word the default font for Headings is Cambria and for the Body style it's Calibri.

The problem is that Google Docs includes neither of these fonts.

Is there a way to add missing fonts to Google Docs or get it to preserve the existing document fonts?

Comment: Calibri and Cambria are both available for me
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vo0F.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible. Google recently [added](http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2010/09/more-fontastic-google-docs.html) more fonts to the list and they will continue adding I guess. They won't let you to upload your own fonts or using external ones (since the removed the ability to edit css/html), because there is going to be an issue if you are going to share the Document and your collaborators won't be able to view it properly. Also there is a privacy issue that might arise.